# Pass control from a parent view's PanResponder to a child views PanResponder

Tags: react-native

I got a Component like this:

```
<View
  { ...this._rangePanResponder.panHandlers } >

    <View
      { ...this._sliderPanResponder.panHandlers } />

</View>
```

When I tap on the child view, it's the parent view's PanResponder which receives and handles the event. I would like to pass the control to the child view.

There is a target property (node id) on the nativeEvent that the PanResponder receives, but I cannot figure out how to map that node id to a view in my component. Is that even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you tap exactly over the child it should be the child's panResponder who handles it.

However you are passing the slider pans as props so I guess you could set them inside the child's constructor:

```
constructor (props) {
  this.panResponder = props._sliderPanResponder.panHandlers
}
```